# solving equation with three unknowns, step by step - solve for p?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if someone could help me, I am not the greatest at math and have my limits unfortunately. I have a problem as shown below, it involves three variables which the problem is solved for the variable p, but has also got variables of d and x. The problem is solved, however i was looking for a step by step process on how it was actually solved? so as i can solve future issues like this. if any one could help it would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Simon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-You can see the numerical values of the constants $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$.

You have a system of $3$ unknowns
$$A=(B+C)X+Dpd\\E=(Fp+H)X+FpX^2+Fpd^2+G\\X=2d-3490$$ You can go easily to a system of $2$ equations with $2$ unknowns eliminating $X$ explicitely given by $(3)$. You get

$$A=(B+C)(2d-3490)+Dpd\\E=Fp+H(2d-3490)+Fp(2d-3490)+Fpd^2+G$$ You need to arrive to an equation with one unknown. You choose eliminate $p$ because it is in the first degree while the unknown $d$ is in second degree. So you do have
$$p=\dfrac{A-(B+C)(2d-3490)}{Dd}=\dfrac{E-H(2d-3490)-G}{F+F(2d-3490)+Fd^2}$$ This gives you, after simplification, a cubic equation in $d$ what is a problem many times difficult for beginners. Obviously you have to calculate the numerical values in place and either, solve the cubic equation if you can or believe the given result.

I hope this could be useful for you.

Comment: Many thanks for looking at this Piquito much appreciated, with regards the first line you refer values of A, B, C and D in the first equation, althou I only see 3 constants? i.e. 3000x 10^3 = A, B = 2901.3, C = 870? where does D come from p? Apologies for maybe simple questions, I am trying to get to a point where I can set up a excel sheet to do this automatically so as I don't need to go through this process each time as the same scenario is repeated a lot for the same problem.